# Javascript: Using Function Chaining to Rearrange Multidimensional Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

My title is slightly off, apologies, having trouble coming up with the right terms atm.

I am trying to do things functionally with `.map()`, `.forEach()`, etc.

I have a structure from a JSON like this, (**all Items are unique strings, some contain spaces**):

```
data = {
  Category1: ["Item_A", "Item_B", "Item_C"]
  Category2: ["Item_D", "Item_E", "Item_F"]
  Category3: ["Item_G", "Item_H"]
}
```

I would like this:

```
data = {
  Item_A: ["Category1"]
  Item_B: ["Category1"]
  Item_C: ["Category1"]
  Item_D: ["Category2"]
  Item_E: ["Category2"]
  Item_F: ["Category2"]
  Item_G: ["Category3"]
  Item_H: ["Category3"]
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Are you sure that this is JSON?

Comment: it's read from a JSON with d3.json(<url>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your `data` with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to replace each `{ key : array }` pair with a flat array of `[value, [key]]` pairs, then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create your desired output:

```js
const data = {
  Category1: ["Item_A", "Item_B", "Item_C"],
  Category2: ["Item_D", "Item_E", "Item_F"],
  Category3: ["Item_G", "Item_H"],
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).flatMap(([k, a]) => a.map(v => [v, [k]]))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. I was not aware of the .flatMap() function.

Comment: @Skyehawk no worries - I'm glad I could help. `.flatMap` is a nice (and slightly more efficient) shortcut for `.map.flat`