# how can swap the key and array of values, of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value, swap

This is my data:

```
obj = Object {
  Great Lakes: Array(3) ["Michigan", "Indiana", "Ohio"]
  Heartland: Array(2) ["Missouri", "Illinois"]
}
```

How can I change it to something like one by one:

```
{"Illinois": "Heartland", "Michigan": "Great Lakes", ...}
```

**I have to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), *Object.entries* and *Array.flat()***.

I used : `namemap = new Map(Object.entries(obj).map(function ([k, v]) {return [v, k];} ))`
but this is not I want or maybe this is not complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Using Function Chaining to Rearrange Multidimensional Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188284/javascript-using-function-chaining-to-rearrange-multidimensional-javascript-obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you just need to iterate the values in each array in `obj`:

```js
const obj = {
  'Great Lakes': ["Michigan", "Indiana", "Ohio"],
  'Heartland': ["Missouri", "Illinois"]
}

const namemap = new Map(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, a]) => a.map(v => [v, k]))
    .flat()
)

for (const [key, value] of namemap.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key} : ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: with a little change: 
namemap = Object.fromEntries(new Map(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, a]) => a.map(v => [v, k]))
    .flat()
))

Comment: @FatemeNazari Sorry, I thought you wanted a `Map`; if you don't, just remove the `new Map` completely. `namemap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(agr) .map(([k, a]) => a.map(v => [v, k])) .flat() )`

Comment: yeahh that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of `.reduce` and `.forEach` to get the value you need

```js
let data = {
  'Great Lakes':["Michigan", "Indiana", "Ohio"],
  'Heartland': ["Missouri", "Illinois"]
}

let result = Object
  .entries(data)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
    value.forEach((v) => acc[v] = key) || acc
  , {})
console.log(result)
```